# Time to Seconds and Seconds to Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have My Code below,

```
    Before=document.getElementsByName("beforehr[]");
    After=document.getElementsByName("afterhr[]");
    MonthTotal=0
    for(i=0;i<Before.length;i++){
        BeforeInSeconds= // Convert Before[i].value to Seconds
        AfterInSeconds= // Convert After[i].value to Seconds
        MonthTotal=parseInt(MonthTotal)+ parseInt(BeforeInSeconds)+parseInt(AfterInSeconds);

}
MonthTotalHRS= // Convert MonthTotal value to Time
document.getElementById("txtMonthTotal").value=MonthTotal;
document.getElementById("Mthtotal").innerHTML=MonthTotalHRS;
```

I need to convert the Before Hours to Seconds, After Hours to Seconds, sum All the Seconds and convert to Time and put it into Mthtotal

Comment: `hours*3600` will convert your hours to seconds. So `+Before[i].value*3600` and `+After[i].value*3600` will give you the seconds version of before and after

Comment: My Time Format is "1:0:0"(hours:seconds:minutes) like this, so how can i use  "hours*3600" formula

Comment: Tried this alert(Before[i].value*3600); But alerts NaN

Comment: Can you post your html? What sort of input type are the elements with names beforehr and afterhr ?

Comment: <td><input type='text' name='beforehr[]' onchange='CalOt()' value='1:0:0'></td><td><input type='text' name='afterhr[]'  onchange='CalOt()'  value='4:0:0'></td>   This is it

Comment: " hours :  minutes : seconds " is the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.split(':')` to split up your time format into an array. Where index 0 is the hour, index 1 is the minutes and index 2 is the seconds. You can then convert each time unit into seconds.

Hours to seconds: `hour*3600`

Minutes to seconds: `minutes*60`

Seconds to seconds: `seconds*1` so just `seconds`

Doing all of this will give you your total result:

```js
var before = [...document.getElementsByName("beforehr[]")];
var after = [...document.getElementsByName("afterhr[]")];

var monthTotal = 0
for (i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
  var beforeTime = before[i].value.split(':');
  var afterTime = after[i].value.split(':');
  
  var hourSeconds = +beforeTime[0] * 3600; // Convert the hours to seconds
  var minuteSeconds = +beforeTime[1] * 60; // Convert the mins to secs
  var seconds = +beforeTime[2]; // No conversions needed for secs to secs
 
  var beforeInSeconds = hourSeconds + minuteSeconds + seconds;
  
  // The above can be compresed into one line. I'll repeat the above for the afterTime on one line as an example:
  var afterInSeconds = (+afterTime[0] * 3600) + (+afterTime[1] * 60) + (+afterTime[2])
  monthTotal += parseInt(beforeInSeconds) + parseInt(afterInSeconds);
}

console.log("Month total in seconds", monthTotal)

// Hours, minutes and seconds (round down)
var hrs = ~~(monthTotal / 3600);
var mins = ~~((monthTotal % 3600) / 60);
var secs = ~~monthTotal % 60;

console.log("Month total in H:M:S", hrs +':' +mins + ':' + secs);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1:0:0" name="beforehr[]" />
<input type="text" value="1:0:0" name="beforehr[]" />

<br />

<input type="text" value="4:0:0" name="afterhr[]" />
<input type="text" value="4:0:0" name="afterhr[]" />
```

Also, note the unary `+` operator is similar to `parseInt` (it acts a little differently however).

The `~~` is simply just a fancy way of saying `Math.floor(number)`

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that variables Before and After are arrays.

```js
var Before = [1, 2]; //180 Secs
var After = [3, 4]; // 420 Secs
var MonthTotal=0;

function secondsToHms(d) {  // Function to convert Secs to H:m:s
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour " : " hours ") : "";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute " : " minutes ") : "";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}

for(i=0;i<Before.length;i++)
{
 BeforeInSeconds= Before[i] * 60;
 AfterInSeconds= After[i] * 60;
 MonthTotal=parseInt(MonthTotal)+ parseInt(BeforeInSeconds)+parseInt(AfterInSeconds);
}
console.log(MonthTotal); //600 Secs

var convertedop=secondsToHms(MonthTotal);
alert(convertedop);
```

Comment: Not My Time Format

Comment: Ok. I just posted with logic. But anyways nick parsons answer was better and more clear than mine.

Comment: Welcome @Brindha.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Simplified

```
<script>
    function CalOt(){
        Before=document.getElementsByName("beforehr[]");
        After=document.getElementsByName("afterhr[]");
        TodayOt=document.getElementsByName("txtTodayOt[]");
        MonthTotal=0
        for(i=0;i<Before.length;i++){
            //alert(TimetoSec(Before[i].value));
            BeforeInSeconds=TimetoSec(Before[i].value); //Convert Before[i].value to Seconds
            AfterInSeconds=TimetoSec(After[i].value);//Convert After[i].value to Seconds
            Daytot=parseInt(BeforeInSeconds)+parseInt(AfterInSeconds);
            TodayOt[i].value=SecToTime(Daytot);
        MonthTotal=parseInt(MonthTotal)+parseFloat(Daytot);

}
MonthTotalHRS=SecToTime(MonthTotal);// Convert MonthTotal value to Time
document.getElementById("txtMonthTotal").value=MonthTotal;
document.getElementById("Mthtotal").innerHTML=MonthTotalHRS;
}
function TimetoSec(Time){
    TimeSplit=Time.split(":");
    HoursSeconds=TimeSplit[0]*60*60;
    Minutes=TimeSplit[1]*60;
    TotalSec=parseFloat(HoursSeconds)+parseFloat(Minutes)+parseFloat(TimeSplit[2]);
    console.log(TotalSec+"\n");
    return TotalSec;
}
function SecToTime(Seconds){
    Hr=Math.floor(Seconds/(60*60));
    Mn=Seconds % (60*60);
    Min=Math.floor(Mn/(60));
    Sec=Mn % (60);
    return Hr+":"+Min+":"+Sec;

}
</script>
```